# help me to proceed with drupal views?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, view, drupal-views

I am newbie to drupal , I just created a view called "master" and i wanna manipulate the output pro grammatically  for creating widget (javascript widget can embed in other website).

```
  $view = views_get_view('master');
  $view->set_display('page');
  $view->execute();
  $viewArray = $view->result;
  $title = $view->display['default']->display_options['title'];
  echo "<h2>$title</h2>";
  echo("<pre>"); print_r ($viewArray); echo("</pre>");
```

It prints the result(in object form), But the output contains only 10 result which was mentioned while at the time of views creation.Please guide me,

```
1.how to get the next 10 result pro grammatically (pagination) ?

2.how to theme a views  pro grammatically (since its js widget) ?

3.any live demo tutorial links to play with advanced views?

4.how to do sorting (whether i need to pass through url)?

5.how deal this with handler object?
```

my view preview looks like this below image

[image]

Thanxs,

Nithish.

Answer (score 1):

Well, for #1 all you need to do is go into the edit control panel for that view and change the number of records to be shown on each page. Setting it to 0 lets it display all records at once.

For the others ... I wonder if `views` is the right solution for you. I suspect you might be better off with a custom module that returns a lot of `drupal_json()` calls. At very least, it's cumbersome and wasteful to be doing all this through views, since views spends so many cycles on rendering.

If you want to avoid coding a custom module, I'd suggest installing the View Bonus Pack (http://drupal.org/project/views_bonus) and using the 'Feed' display types. This will make it marginally easier to manipulate the results with js.

Comment: hmm im working for maintenance website and my client asked for only through views and he also have views_bonus preinstalled in his site. anyway i try to find the way